# MEAN stack user delete

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I've got a users list with delete button on `/users` url. My delete route looks like this:

```
app.route('/users/:userId')
    .get(users.read)
    .put(users.updateById)
    .delete(users.delete);
app.param('userId', users.userById);
```

But problem is, that my delete button is calling delete on `/users` url, so I'm getting `DELETE http://localhost:3000/users 404 (Not Found)`. How can I solve this problem? My controller remove() function you can see below. How can I pass `'/user/' + user._id` to it? User is removed correctly only from scope :(

```
$scope.remove = function(id) {
    var user = $scope.users[id];
    var modalOptions = {
        closeButtonText: 'Cancel',
        actionButtonText: 'Delete user',
        headerText: 'Delete ' + user.displayName + '?',
        bodyText: 'Are you sure you want to delete this user?'
    };

    modalService.showModal({}, modalOptions).then(function() {
        if (user) {
            user.$remove();

            for (var i in $scope.users) {
                if ($scope.users[i] === user) {
                    $scope.users.splice(i, 1); // remove item from scope
                }
            }
        }
    });

};
```

user service is basic from mean.js installation

```
angular.module('users').factory('Users', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('users', {}, {
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Comment: Looks like your user.$remove method isn't setup properly. How are you defining it?

Comment: What settings do you think? `exports.delete` function in my server controller?

Comment: For example, if it's using an angular resource to perform the ajax request, the resource isn't set up to properly pass the user id in the url rather than the json. Your problem is with angular at the moment, unless you want to change your server routes. What generator (if any) did you use to build your project?

Comment: I am using mean.js and with yo generator :)

Comment: Can you show us your user service?

Comment: I pasted it in post, now I know, where is the problem :-) Could you tell me, how should I edit the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular resources by default have the following methods: get, save, query, remove, delete. unless otherwise specified, they will not pass the param in the url the way you need them to. In this case, you need to specify the `remove` method and ensure that the param gets passed in the url.

```
angular.module('users').factory('Users', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('users', {}, { 
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            remove: {
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: 'users/:id',
                params: {id: '@_id'}
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

this assumes your user objects have an `_id` property, which is common in the mean stack. You should probably setup get save and update the same way.